# Android How can I read json file(text file) from SD Card and display data into textview

Tags: android, json, android-json

I have the following textfile into my SdCard.now i want to parse this file via Json parser,and i want to parse and read this file and display data into my textview,how i can do this?

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Farhan Shah",
        "duration": 10,
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Noman Shah",
        "duration": 10,
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "Ahmad Shah",
        "duration": 10,
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "Mohsin Shah",
        "duration": 10,
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "title": "Haris Shah",
        "duration": 10,
    }
  ]

}
```

This is the code:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    //Get the text file

    File file = new File(sdcard,"textarabics.txt");

    String UTF8 = "utf8";
    int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;


    //Read text from file
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
```

i get the file,but now i have no idea that how i can parse the data?

Comment: Is the problem reading the file or parsing the file, I assume you know how to show something in a textview.

Comment: i want to parse this file through json and display data into my textview

Comment: @PhilippJahoda edit my code please checked..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Read the JSON file using [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) from SD card and use [JSONObject](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) to parse it.

Here a starting code:

```
    import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class ReadJsonFile {
public ReadFile (){ 
            try {
            File yourFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "path/to/the/file/inside_the_sdcard/textarabics.txt");
            FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(yourFile);
            String jsonStr = null;
            try {
                FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
                MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());

                jsonStr = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
              }
              catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
              }
              finally {
                stream.close();
              }
/*  String jsonStr = "{\n\"data\": [\n    {\n        \"id\": \"1\",\n        \"title\": \"Farhan Shah\",\n        \"duration\": 10\n    },\n    {\n        \"id\": \"2\",\n        \"title\": \"Noman Shah\",\n        \"duration\": 10\n    },\n    {\n        \"id\": \"3\",\n        \"title\": \"Ahmad Shah\",\n        \"duration\": 10\n    },\n    {\n        \"id\": \"4\",\n        \"title\": \"Mohsin Shah\",\n        \"duration\": 10\n    },\n    {\n        \"id\": \"5\",\n        \"title\": \"Haris Shah\",\n        \"duration\": 10\n    }\n  ]\n\n}\n";
  */     
                 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting data JSON Array nodes
                JSONArray data  = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

                // looping through All nodes
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String title = c.getString("title");
                    String duration = c.getString("duration");
                    //use >  int id = c.getInt("duration"); if you want get an int


                    // tmp hashmap for single node
                    HashMap<String, String> parsedData = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    parsedData.put("id", id);
                    parsedData.put("title", title);
                    parsedData.put("duration", duration);


                    // do what do you want on your interface
                  }


           } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
}
```

Ddon't forget to add read storage on your mainfest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Dear Thanks for ur reply,,kindely tell me JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr); in the perameter,what is jsonStr?it's give me error.

Comment: thats frap prob, check my edits jsonStr is a String

Comment: dear when i come to this point JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);..... its crash,any idea about this,this is my crash report..  org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: That can happen if you have problem json data format (something like not closed "{" bracket) your file maybe not completely done inside your string be sure that your JSONObject constructor contain a string like that:  new JSONObject("{your string}") , log it before pass the string to the constructor Log.i("MY JSON", jsonStr);

Comment: {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Farhan Shah",
            "duration": 10,
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Noman Shah",
            "duration": 10,
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "title": "Ahmad Shah",
            "duration": 10,
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "title": "Mohsin Shah",
            "duration": 10,
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "title": "Haris Shah",
            "duration": 10,
        }
    ]
    
}

Comment: data coming fine..now does't know why it's crash..

Comment: it's malformed remove the "," after "duration" before close bracket: { "id": "4", "title": "Mohsin Shah", "duration": 10  }

Comment: in log this is the output now: { "data": [ { "id": "1", "title": "Farhan Shah", "duration": 10 }, { "id": "2", "title": "Noman Shah", "duration": 3 }, { "id": "3", "title": "Ahmad Shah", "duration": 5 }, { "id": "4", "title": "Mohsin Shah", "duration": 7 }, { "id": "5", "title": "Haris Shah", "duration": 4 } ] }

Comment: is it the same crash?

Comment: yes it is the same crash

Comment: you have correct imports?

Comment: yes everything is fine and json data come in to log check this,i have posted the crash question too  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969485/android-org-json-jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-convert/21969569?noredirect=1#comment33289566_21969569

Comment: i am stuck badly,plz help

Comment: u can change my json file and suggested me changes into my json file

Comment: bundle of thanks bro,also u have suggested me changes into my json text file then i will be change according to ur sugession,in json text file i just need to the "title" and "duration"..

Comment: the json text file i made my self..wat u say if we can remove the json array "data"?we just need the json objects like "title" and "duration"

Comment: my code work using copy and past, ur format is gd don't change it ive used ur json in string , check edits

Comment: not working bro..same issue still rises..

Comment: bro issue is resolved bundle of thanks so much :)

Comment: ur ans is accepted..the issue is that the textarabics.txt file i am saving on unicode..that is the reason of issue..thanks bro much appreciated ur support :)

Answer (score 4):

get the file contents like this:

```
File yourFile = new File("/mnt/extSdCard/test.json");
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(yourFile);
        String jString = null;
        try {
            FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
            MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
            /* Instead of using default, pass in a decoder. */
            jString = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
          }
          finally {
            stream.close();
          }
```

parse and add to listview:

```
String[] from = new String[] {"title"};
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name};
List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

try 
{
    JSONArray names = new JSONArray(jsonString);
    Log.i("MyList","Number of names " + names.length());
    for (int j = 0; j < names.length(); j++) 
    {
         JSONObject jsonObject = names.getJSONObject(j);
         HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
         map.put("title", jsonObject.getString("title"));
         fillMaps.add(map);
    }
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, fillMaps, R.layout.result, from, to);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here mListView is your predefined ListView.

Comment: JSONArray names = new JSONArray(jsonString); in the perameter what is the jsonString?

Answer (score 4):

Following may be useful, which I have taken from android developer site.

In order to read or write files on the external storage, your app must acquire the  `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` system permissions.

You can set the permissions in your manifest file like this:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Here are a couple methods you can use to check the availability:

```
/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
        Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Read the file content as given below. After that you can process,

```
final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                          .getAbsolutePath(), filename);
```