# Android json download and implement

Tags: android, json, googleio

The android app i'm developing has a hardcoded json file which is used to load data on mobile for the first time.

Now,during runtime on mobile, there would be another json file on my server and I would like to download that json in background and implement it instead of the previous json.

It would be like refreshing data by implementing new json files.

How should i do it.??

Answer (score 0):

You can download file with Download Manager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html).
Then you must read your file as json (see [Reading a json file in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814503/reading-a-json-file-in-android) or [Android How can I read json file(text file) from SD Card and display data into textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968161/android-how-can-i-read-json-filetext-file-from-sd-card-and-display-data-into-t)). Then you can read data from json and reload data.